# Combining Code together C++

Tags: c++

Ive written two solutions of code, the first one reads data from a file into a vector then does some calculations and stores new data back in the vector, the second one is a GUI that allows me to create a new textfile. They both work individually but combining them into one solution is difficult, as there 2x `int main()` plus a `class` in one and `struct` in the other. any help would be great?

Comment: Rename your `main` function to something else and call it from the GUI app?  or vice-versa.

Comment: @GWW is that relatively easy to do? how do i call it from the GUI app?

Comment: You could compile each as separate files and link them together at the end.

Comment: @GWW Better yet, Add DLLMain to the backend, rename the backend main to invoke(), compile to a DLL and call invoke() from the GUI main.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap them up in the proper data structure.

A c++ program will always only contain one main entry point.  It's your job as a programmer to divide the logic up, well, logically.

In this case, you may want to create a method/function that reads data from the file. I'd stick the GUI in it's own separate class.

This question seems a bit odd and it's obvious you're new to programming. Read up a bit more on data structures and the c++ language.

Answer (score 1):

You could have one program call the executable of another program (this is fairly popular in UNIX systems).

The other option would be to rename the main function and change the parameters it receives, then merge both codes, make sure you compile and link the classes together, and call the functions of one from the other.

I don't get the problem with class and struct, as long as they're not using the same name. If they are, you'll have to rename one of them, or simply remove one and use the other, if the functionality is exactly the same.